# Hide "Contract" content type from content create list for all users except group "Contract Managers" Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

How can i hide "Contract" content type from content create list for all users except group "CONTRACT_MANAGERS". I added the config evaluator in share to add the contract to the list of documents and created evaluator extension with the group but it continues to display for all users.

**share-config.xml file**

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">

        <create-content>

            <content id="contract" label="Contract" type="pagelink" index="1" icon="text">

                <param name="page">create-content?destination={nodeRef}&amp;itemId=udp:contract</param>

                <evaluator negate="true">za.co.udp.evaluator.doclib.action.permissionManager</evaluator>

            </content>          

        </create-content>

    </config>
```

**application-context.xml** file

```
<bean id="za.co.udp.evaluator.doclib.action.permissionManager" parent="evaluator.doclib.action.groupMembership">

        <property name="groups">

            <list>

                <value>GROUP_CONTRACT_MANAGERS</value>

            </list>

        </property>

</bean>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks OK. But why you have `negate="true"` in `<evaluator negate="true">`? It's negative your evaluator and make right opposite of your goal. So now every user EXCEPT group GROUP_CONTRACT_MANAGERS will see this content type. Make sure too that your group ID is right GROUP_CONTRACT_MANAGERS.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, isn't something missing in addition to the bean and evaluator (in share-config.xml)?